# Crawling multiple sites with Python Scrapy with limited depth per site

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to Scrapy and I am trying to crawl multiple sites from a text file with CrawlSpider. However I would like to limit the depth of scraping *per* site and also the total number of crawled pages again *per* web site. Unfortunately, when the start_urls and allowed_domains attributes are set the response.meta['depth'] always seems to be zero (this doesn't happen when I am trying to scrape individual sites). Setting the DEPTH_LIMIT in the settings file doesn't seem to do anything at all.
When I remove the **init** definition and simply set the start_urls and allowed_domains things seem to be working fine.
Here is the code (Sorry for the indentation -- this is not the issue):

```
class DownloadSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'downloader'
  rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
  def __init__(self, urls_file, N=10):
      data = open(urls_file, 'r').readlines()[:N]
      self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(i).hostname.strip() for i in data] 
      self.start_urls = ['http://' + domain for domain in self.allowed_domains]

  def parse_start_url(self, response):
      return self.parse_item(response)

  def parse_item(self, response):
      print response.url
      print response.meta['depth']
```

This results in response.meta['depth'] always equal to zero and the cralwer only crawls the very first site of each element of start_urls (i.e. it doesn't follow any links). So I have two questions
1) How to limit the crawl to a certain depth *per* each site in start_urls
2) How to limit the total number of crawls per site irrespective of the depth

Thanks !

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the part where you pass arguments to the spider. If this is removed the crawler works just fine with DEPTH_LIMIT setting. However, this makes it very inefficient in feeding it a changing set of sites to crawl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to call the base class constructors (for example with `super`):

```
def __init__(self, urls_file, N=10, *a, **kw):
    data = open(urls_file, 'r').readlines()[:N]
    self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(i).hostname.strip() for i in data]
    self.start_urls = ['http://' + domain for domain in self.allowed_domains]
    super(DownloadSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

**UPDATE:**

When you *override* a method in Python the base class method is no longer called and instead your new method is called, this means that if you want your new logic to run *in addition* to the old logic (i.e. not instead of), then you need to call the old logic manually.

Here is the logic that you were missing by not calling the [`CrawlSpider.__init__()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/96c2332e0ecded5fb883cbf04b017ea318750017/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py#L34) (via `super(DownloadSpider, self).__init__()`):

```
self._compile_rules()
```

Comment: THanks. This fixed it (although I still have no idea why -- I will continue to comb through the documentation in scrapy)